# Looping through event listeners in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, addeventlistener

```
for (var i=0; i<=98; i++) {
    box1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func(i));
}
function func(i:int):Function{
    return function paint(e:MouseEvent):void{
        var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
        if (i%4==0) {
            myColorTransform.color = 0xFF0000;
        }
        else if (i%4==1) {
            myColorTransform.color = 0x0000FF;
        }
        else if (i%4==2) {
            myColorTransform.color = 0x00FF00;
        }
        else if (i%4==3) {
            myColorTransform.color = 0xFFFF00;
        }
        box1.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
    }
}
```

I want to run a loop through the event listeners in such a way that whenever I click the object its color transforms into the next one. The above code just changes the color once and produces the color for the last value of i (98) which is green. Please help. I am beginner to ActionScript.

Comment: The above code would lead to issues as it is impossible to remove your Event Listeners. Each time you `return function(e:Event){...}` you create a new instance of a function with no persistent reference, any attempt to `removeEventListener()`  would fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its will be enough one event listener and some counter. Something like that (not tested):

```
var clickCounter:uint = 0;

box1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBoxClick);

function onBoxClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    if (clickCounter%4==0) {
        myColorTransform.color = 0xFF0000;
    }
    else if (clickCounter%4==1) {
        myColorTransform.color = 0x0000FF;
    }
    else if (clickCounter%4==2) {
        myColorTransform.color = 0x00FF00;
    }
    else if (clickCounter%4==3) {
        myColorTransform.color = 0xFFFF00;
    }
    box1.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
    clickCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you shouldn't do it this way, in your example, each time you click the box1, you will trigger 98 times func() , and the last time it's trigger, i is equal to 98, I don't think it's what you expect...

A best way to do this, is to store your i somewhere, you can store it into box1 for example ( if it's a movieclip ) , then you can retrieve it, read and increase it easily in your paint() method.
This way you only have to have 1 addEventListener on your box1.